# Testcontainers JDBC URL scheme lifecycle

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

According to the [docs](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/): "... to get a fresh containerized instance of the database each time your application starts up"

But what this really means taking into account Spring Boot context caching? Will I get one container for all tests in the project or per context or per test?

Let's imagine I have several tests with several contexts:

- Test A.1 with context A (@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ContextA.class))
- Test A.2 with context A
- ...
- Test B.1 with context B (@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ContextB.class))
- Test B.2 with context B
- ...

Can I be sure that all tests within the context will use the same container?